# Restrictions on Bundle Identifiers

Tags: ios, xcode4

I am building an app whose name starts with a digit rather than an alpha character.  Xcode4 insists on converting a digit in the first position of the product name to a hyphen in the bundle identifier.  I know I can override the bundle name in the info.plist file and replace ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier} with a literal such as 22catch.

If I do this, is it going to cause me any problems further down the line when I come to upload the project to the appstore for approval?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No it will not create any issue. You can also change bundle identifier. It is not necessary to use Exact an me of project in Bundle identifier. You can use different one

Answer (score 0):

In best of my knowledge , when you upload in Appstore , in that time there you will  give a app name .
so I think it will not create any  issue in future.